# Swift Continue Flow in TableView(didSelectRowAt IndexPath) after presenting Alert Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm wanting to present an UIAlertController when a user taps a row in a tableView when `condition` isn't equal to 1. Once the alert is dismissed, I'm wanting the remaining code in `didSelectRowAt IndexPath` to execute. However, the flow stops. I assume I'm needing something other than `nil` in `completion:` but I'm stumped.

I'm presenting the Alert Controller like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if condition != 1 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        condition = 1
    }

    \\remaining code to be executed
}
```

Comment: Write the remaining code in the handler of the alert action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the code to be executed in the action handler of the defaultAction. Thus the code will be executed after the ok button is pressed. If you put it in present() method completion, it will be executed exact after the alert is presented.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Nai", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        print("Executed after ok tapped")
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true) {
        print("Executed when its presented")
    }
```

Comment: THANKS! I had tried wrapping the code in a function and calling it that way but I didn't have it in an enclosure...